# rqt_plot for data in DignosticArray message

Tags: ros, array, rostopic, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying (unsuccessfully) to plot /diagnostics/status[0]/values[0]/value (a stringified floating point number).

Is such a topic string supported by rostopic or rqt_plot ?  If so, how do I access the value of interest ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193426/rqt_plot-for-data-in-dignosticarray-message/) by [john.novak](https://answers.ros.org/users/20294/john.novak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-09-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sadly, you can't plot strings in rqt_plot, and the diagnostics messages don't support floating-point diagnostic values.

You may want to look at the [diagnostic_analysis](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostic_analysis) package for alternate ways to analyze diagnostic data, or consider publishing your numeric data on a dedicated topic.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0